# Increase space between bars in a stacked bar chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data such as this:

```
data_in <- read_table2("Programcomponent    name    descending_order    descending_order2   group   value
A   Biology 1   1   Group1  1445
B   Science 2   2   Group1  832
C   Sociology   3   4   Group1  661
C-2 Sociology2  4   4   Group1  342
D   Arts    5   6   Group1  221
B-2 Science2    8   3   Group1  150
A   Biology 1   1   Group2  901
B   Science 2   2   Group2  580
C   Sociology   3   4   Group2  442
C-2 Sociology2  4   4   Group2  293
D   Arts    5   6   Group2  163
B-2 Science2    8   3   Group2  142
A   Biology 1   1   Group3  321
B   Science 2   2   Group3  170
C   Sociology   3   4   Group3  251
C-2 Sociology2  4   4   Group3  107
D   Arts    5   6   Group3  93
B-2 Science2    8   3   Group3  108
")
```

I am trying to create a graph like this. Except that I want column B and B-2 to be grouped together, and column C, C-2 to be grouped together. How might I add space between the bars such that A is one group, B,B2 is another group, C,C2 is another group and D is another group?

If possible, looking for an option that is not faceted.

```
ggplot(data_in,
       aes(fill = group, y = value, #alpha = factor(alphatotal),
           x = reorder(`Programcomponent`, descending_order2), label = value)) + 
  # Specify bar plot
  geom_bar(position = "identity", stat = "identity") + 
  geom_text_repel(aes(label=value),vjust=0,direction = "y")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `facet_grid`

```
data_in$grp = substring(data_in$Programcomponent, 0, 1)
graphics.off()
ggplot(data_in, aes(x = Programcomponent, y = value, fill = group)) +
    geom_bar(position = "identity", stat = "identity") + 
    facet_grid(~ grp, space = "free", scales = "free")
```

Comment: thanks, I guess facet grid is an option. My actual X program components are not named A,B etc., is there a way to use the alphabet to subset like you have, while making the real names show? I'll update my example data!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you could add the following line to convert the program component codes to the name... `+ scale_x_discrete(labels = c("A" = "Biology", "B" = "Science", "C" = "Sociology",  "C-2" = "sociology2", "B-2" = "Science2", "D" = "Arts"))`